# compute the residue of $\frac{z}{e^z - 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Can someone show how to compute the residue of this function: 
$$\frac{z}{e^z - 1}$$

I think can represent the Taylor series of $e^z$ as 
$$e^z = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots$$
Then, we have 
$$\frac{z}{e^z - 1} = \frac{z}{(1 +z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots) -1}$$
$$ = 1 + 1 +\frac{2}{z} + \frac{3!}{z^2} + \cdots - 1 = 1 +\frac{2}{z} + \frac{3!}{z^2} + \cdots$$
and, this function has a pole at $z_0 = 2n \pi i$
Hence, $$\operatorname{Res}_{z_0}f(z) = 0$$

EDIT:

The way I used to solve this problem is $$\textrm{Res}_{z_0}(\frac{f}{g}) = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)} = \frac{2n \pi i}{e^{2n \pi i}}$$

Am I correct? If not, can someone please show me how to do it please?

Comment: $e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\dots$ You missed that first $1$.

Comment: Oh, I just edited it. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like it has been edited.

Comment: You seem to be using the fact that $1/(a+b)=1/a+1/b$. Don't do that!

Comment: To be crystal clear, don't use that 'fact' because it's [not a fact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166591/show-that-frac1a-frac1b-not-frac1ab)!

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series of $e^z$ is
$$e^z = 1+ z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots.$$
There is a nice formula for the residue of $f$ at a simple pole $a$:
$$\textrm{Res}_a(f)=\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)f(z).$$

Comment: I know that formula, but I don't know if the main principal part $f(z)$ in this case is $\frac{2}{z}$ or not

Comment: Taylor series:$$\frac{z}{e^z-1}=1 - \frac{z}{2} +\frac{z^2}{12} -\frac{z^4}{720}+\cdots$$

Comment: @Alexander to see that, write $z=(a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...)(e^z-1)$, expand $e^z$ (as you wrote in your post) and then equate the coefficients of like powers

Comment: The way I used to solve is $\textrm{Res}_{z_0}(\frac{f}{g}) = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)} = \frac{2n \pi i}{e^{2n \pi i}}$

Answer (score 1):

Use the following rule: If $f(z)={p(z)\over q(z)}$, and $q$ has a simple zero at $a$ then
$${\rm res}(f | a)={p(a)\over q'(a)}\ .$$
The denominator of the given function $f$ has simple zeros at the points $z_k:=2k\pi i$, and $q'(z_k)=e^{z_k}=1$ for all $k$. It follows that
$${\rm res}(f | z_k)=z_k=2k\pi i\qquad(k\in{\mathbb Z})\ ;$$
in particular, the function $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$.